# JS returns "Maximum call stack size exceeded" and "Stack Overflow" when using timepicker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, timepicker

I used gem 'jquery-timepicker-rails' in the project. 
In my haml file I used this:

```
.span3= f.input :start_time, as: :string, input_html: {id: 'stime', class: "timepicker", value: ( @class_session.new_record? ? "09:00" : @class_session.start_time.try(:strftime, "%H:%M") ), remote: true}
.span3= f.input :end_time, as: :string, input_html: {class: "timepicker", value: ( @class_session.new_record? ? "10:00" : @class_session.end_time.try(:strftime, "%H:%M") )}
```

The JS code is:

```
:javascript
$('.timepicker').timepicker();
```

After I click on the timepicker elements and select value, if I click other elements on the page, it will return

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(^|.)ui-timepicker(.|$)/: Stack overflow

If I use nested form to add a new form, it returns

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: You get this error when a lot of function calls happen from your jquery which is pushed to a stack and hence  Max stack exceeded error. I recon somewhere in your code you have a loop of function calls or scenario like function1 calls function2 which inturn calls function1 and so on... Check your code for such programming errors

Comment: Thanks @Reddy. I think I have misunderstood the problem. I have edited the question. It is actually two problems. If I use nested form, whenever I add or delete a form, it returns "Maximum call stack size exceeded". But even I don't use nested form, just as the simple example above, I got the stack overflow error.

Comment: Not into ruby-on-rails. If you think its only because of Jquery then you can create a JSFiddle and many will be ready to solve your problem as they all can have access to the fiddle. Now I am not sure if this is because of any other code except jquery